# Multiple SELECT in mysql command

Tags: mysql, select

I have the MySQL command

```
SELECT Name FROM `User_Info` WHERE username="USERNAME" AND password="PASSWORD"
```

But I was wondering how I could specify multiple SELECTS.

For example:

```
SELECT Name AND email FROM `User_Info` WHERE username="USERNAME" AND password="PASSWORD"
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate return fields by commas.

```
SELECT Name, email 
FROM User_Info WHERE username="USERNAME" 
AND password="PASSWORD"
```

You might want to consider looking for an SQL tutorial.  This is not really the right forum for these types of questions.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, and I apologize if this wasnt supposed to be posted here.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it here in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html).

What you'd need it

```
SELECT Name, email
FROM `User_Info`
WHERE username="USERNAME"
    AND password="PASSWORD"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a comma?

```
SELECT Name, email FROM `User_Info` WHERE username="USERNAME" AND password="PASSWORD"
```

If you're stumped on this you really need to invest in a decent SQL reference.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to separate the fields with a comma.

```
Select name, email, password from user_info where username = "USER" and password = "PASS"
```

In case you want to select all fields only use *

```
Select * from user_info
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do the following:

```
SELECT Name, email FROM `User_Info` WHERE username="USERNAME" AND password="PASSWORD"
```

The full details on the SELECT statement can be found here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html